# in React, I call two lists to page from mongo and I want to click one to filter what is shown in other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

[This is the relevant part of my page to hopefully make it clearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guYi6.png)

I am working on a project where i have 2 mongo collections and collection A (list of symptoms) all have items from collection B (conditions) they are related to.

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc4bc92b6523a203423f2fa"),
    "name" : "Cough",
    "symptoms" : [ 
        ObjectId("5dc4bc19299dfc46843a65f0"), 
        ObjectId("5dc4bc19299dfc46843a65f2")
    ]
```

and vice versa

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc4bc19299dfc46843a65f0"),
    "name" : "Lung Cancer",
    "description" : "blah blah string",
    "symptoms" : [ 
        ObjectId("5dc4bc92b6523a203423f2fa")
    ]
```

My code where I call them looks like this

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        conditions: [],
        symptoms: [],
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getConditionsMethod();
        this.getSymptomsMethod();
    }
    getConditionsMethod = () => {
        API.getConditions()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
                this.setState({
                    conditions: data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
    getSymptomsMethod = () => {
        API.getSymptoms()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
                this.setState({
                    symptoms: data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
```

and the relevant section of my `render() {return (`

```
                    <Col >
                        <Row>
                            <Col className="symp">
                                <div className="doubleCol">
                                    {this.state.symptoms.map(item => (
                                        <ListItem key={item.ObjectID}>
                                            <input
                                                type="radio"
                                                name="selector"
                                                value="option 2"
                                                checked={false}
                                                className="sympCheck"
                                            />
                                            {item.name}
                                        </ListItem>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col className="cond">
                                <div className="doubleCol">
                                    {this.state.conditions.map(item => (
                                        <ListItem key={item.ObjectID}>
                                            {item.name}
                                        </ListItem>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                             </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
```

my buttons on the symptom list at the moment don't actually do anything. The goal is that onClick of a button the list of conditions will display only those conditions which have that as a symptom instead of rendering all of them. I have thought of a few ways that MIGHT work but haven't actually stared experimenting yet.
Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be great so I don't lose too many hours down rabbit holes of 'this might be a way to do it, nope didn't work'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you might have a little typo in the first code block you posted. A cough (a symptom) should have an array of conditions, not an array of other symptoms, right?

Anyway, you probably want to include a state property called something like 'selectedSymptom' which gets updated each time you select a different symptom.

Then in the Conditions section, instead of rendering the full list of conditions, you can just filter for the ones that include the selectedSymptom in their array of symptoms.

```
{this.state.conditions
  .filter(condition => condition.symptoms.includes(this.state.selectedSymptom))
  .map(item => (
    <ListItem key={item.ObjectID}>
       {item.name}
    </ListItem>
  ))
}
```

Comment: thanks for the catch on the typo. gotta fix the model. i meant to call that one something else.

I am gonna try playing with the state like you suggested, that was one thing i was wondering how hard that would be. From your lines there it looks like it should be the simplest I should also be able to set it where if none selected it displays the full list.

Comment: hmm... looks like i need chcekboxes not radio buttons if i want to be able to select multiples

Answer (score 1):

You could have another state variable, something like "selectedSymptom". Then on click of radio button, you define a method that essentially calls setState and updates the value of "selectedSymptom". In addition, change the map logic in

```
<Col className="cond">
                                <div className="doubleCol">
                                    {this.state.conditions.map(item => (
                                        <ListItem key={item.ObjectID}>
                                            {item.name}
                                        </ListItem>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                             </Col>
```

to filter based off of selectedSymptom. Anytime you set the state variable, re-render will be called and it will automatically filter the list based off of selectedSymptom. Hope that helps.