# changing state of one list and calling method using checkboxes on another list to filter

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

Mods,
This is a continuation of an older question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58922755/in-react-i-call-two-lists-to-page-from-mongo-and-i-want-to-click-one-to-filter). I started to do an edit to that question but things had progressed so far I was rewriting most of it. I am not intending to duplicate the question.

I have 2 mongo collections and collection A (symptoms) all have items from collection B (conditions) they are related to.

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc4bc92b6523a203423f2fa"),
    "name" : "Cough",
    "symptoms" : [ 
        ObjectId("5dc4bc19299dfc46843a65f0"), 
        ObjectId("5dc4bc19299dfc46843a65f2")
    ]
```

and vice versa

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc4bc19299dfc46843a65f0"),
    "name" : "Lung Cancer",
    "description" : "blah blah string",
    "symptoms" : [ 
        ObjectId("5dc4bc92b6523a203423f2fa")
    ]
```

I have the states and functions

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        conditions: [],
        symptoms: [],
        selectedSymptom: []
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getConditionsMethod();
        this.getSymptomsMethod();
    }
    getConditionsMethod = () => {
        API.getConditions()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
                this.setState({
                    conditions: data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
    getSymptomsMethod = () => {
        API.getSymptoms()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
                this.setState({
                    symptoms: data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
    filterConditionsMethod = () => {
        API.getConditions()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
                this.setState({
                    selectedSymptom: data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
```

In my `render() {return` I have checkboxes with the symptoms on the page

```
                                <div className="doubleCol">
                                    {this.state.symptoms.map(item => (
                                        <ListItem key={item.ObjectID}>
                                            <input type="checkbox" className="sympSelect" />
                                            {item.name}
                                        </ListItem>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
```

and I render the conditions here with a filter for which conditions are selected

```
                                <div className="doubleCol">
                                    {this.state.conditions
                                        .filter(condition => condition.symptoms.includes(this.state.selectedSymptom))
                                        .map(item => (
                                            <ListItem key={item.ObjectID}>
                                                {item.name}
                                            </ListItem>
                                        ))}
                                </div>
```

So what I can't figure out is  **A)** How to have the onMount which renders all the conditions do what it is supposed to do first so the filtering only happens after a checkbox is checked.
and **B)** How to make the checkbox change filter data in `filterConditionsMethod` by ObjectID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think I really got what you meant by "make the checkbox change filter data in filterConditionsMethod by ObjectID" so the **B)** question is kind of confusing to me.

As for the **A)** question, unfortunately I can't test it right now, but maybe I could help you if I got it right. You could add another statement for your `filter` when rendering *conditions* to check if any symptom is already selected, and to really filter it by symptoms if that's true. Something like this would do:

```
.filter(condition => !this.state.selectedSymptom.length || condition.symptoms.includes(this.state.selectedSymptom))
```

This way, the `filter` would only return **false** if there is at least one symptom selected (has length > 0) and it does not include one of these selected symptoms. If the first statement returns **true** (!0 = true), the `filter` will return **true** either way because of the **OR** logical operator.

Comment: THANK YOU! **A)** is solved perfectly with that snippet. I guess i was thinking of how to do it in the methods when there was an obvious easy way to do it in the render.

As far as **B)** basically the short version is checking the boxes doesn't DO anything at the moment. I apologize for the confusing wording, I was trying to write out what in my head I thought it should do, but really it was just "don't do nothing when box is checked"